# Powershell string between two characters and last string of line

Tags: powershell

I have such log file:

```
File downloaded C:\path\special_catalog\update_123_132_2.0\firmware.zip foo-bar2.0 status=success
File downloaded C:\path\special_catalog\update_123_132_3.0\firmware.zip foo-bar3.0 status=success
File downloaded C:\path\special_catalog\update_123_132_3.0\firmware.zip foo-bar3.0 status=success
```

Which regex I need to get "update_123_132_2.0" and "status=success" of every line? I don't have a problem with "update_123_132_2.0" because it's string between special_catalog\ and \firmware, but how add to this "status=success"?

Comment: `\\(update_.*?)\\.* (.*)$`

Comment: My output should look like this: "update_123_132_2.0 status=success"/

Comment: So, `(cat 'C:\path\to\your.log') -replace '\\(update_.*?)\\.* (.*)$', '$1 $2'`?

Comment: do you want to use regex as your only option?